# Cain and Abel Dictionary Attack - How many words?

Tags: password-cracking

How many dictionary words in each attempt (e.g. "word1 word2") will Cain and Abel attempt to use before giving up?

I've done some testing and my results seem spotty. For example I've seen it give up on a two word MD5 hash and also crack a 6 word MD5 hash.

Regarding dictionary attack options, I'm just using "As Is".

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that it doesn't try the entire dictionary file you provided?

Comment: Edited the question, thanks @multithr3at3d

Comment: That doesn't really answer multi's question.

Comment: To be more verbose, for each dictionary attack attempt Cain and Abel makes, how many words will it use simultaneously? For example I know that it goes through the dictionary once trying each word alone one time, but I also know through testing that it will try multiple words per attempt like "grey fox" instead of just "fox". What is the max number of words it will try in a single attempt?